# CICoreMLModelFilter - what does it do?

Tags: core-image

I found some documentation on CICoreMLModelFilter. Not much information, and I can't find any example code. I'm not even sure what it does? Is it for classification? Can you overlay images over a face, like those Snapchat-filters? It takes an input image and a Core ML-model and returns an output image. What kind of Core ML-model? You can have a Core ML-model that recognize license plates, and use it on a picture of a pizza. I don't really see the connection here?

Answer (score 2):

I think this filter only works with models that take an image (`CVPixelBuffer`) as input and that output at least one image. The obvious use case here are style transfer models.

In my experience, this filter is not very flexible. For instance, it will simply scale-to-fill the input image before passing it into the model, and will return the output of the model as-is.

If you want more control over the process, I would recommend implementing a custom `CIImageProcessorKernel` that uses Vision or Core ML directly to do the processing.